# MongoDB concurrent queries on different collections are slow

Tags: mongodb, multithreading, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have multiple mongodb collections with 100000 documents in each collection and 10000 columns in each document.
There is a python script which executes aggregate queries in a multi-threaded fashion. Each thread invokes an aggregate on a separate collection.
Here's the corresponding code:

```
import pymongo
import time
import threading
import sys

mongocli = pymongo.MongoClient(host="192.168.99.100", username="admin", password="admin123", \
    authSource="analyse_db")
db = mongocli['analyse_db']
collection = sys.argv[1]
column = sys.argv[2]
threaded = int(sys.argv[3])
# Start times of time column of every collection.
# There are 7 collections for each day in a week.
start_times = [1587288313, 1587374713, 1587461113, 1587547513, 1587633514, 1587719914, 1587806314]
interval = 86000
time_column = "timestamp_EP"

col = db[collection]
group_query = {"$group": {"_id": "", "result": {"$avg": "$" + column}}}

def aggregate_thread(local_col, start_time, end_time, thread_id):
    local_mongocli = pymongo.MongoClient(host="192.168.99.100", username="admin", password="admin123", \
    authSource="analyse_db")
    local_db = local_mongocli['analyse_db']
    local_col_obj = local_db[local_col]
    #cursor = local_col.aggregate([{"$match": {time_column: \
    #    {"$gte": start_time, "$lt": end_time}}}, group_query])
    thr_start_time = time.time()
    cursor = local_col_obj.aggregate([group_query])
    try:
        print(cursor.next())
    except Exception:
        print("no data")
    print("thread " + str(thread_id) + " completion time: ", time.time() - thr_start_time)

def aggregate_threaded():
    thr_list = []
    nthreads = len(start_times)
    for i in range(0, nthreads):
        ftime = start_times[i]
        ttime = ftime + interval
        local_col = collection + "_day" + str(i)
        thr = threading.Thread(target=aggregate_thread, args=[local_col, ftime, ttime, i], daemon=True)
        thr_list.append(thr)
        thr.start()
    for thr in thr_list:
        _res = thr.join()

proc_start = time.time()
aggregate_threaded()
print(time.time() - proc_start)
```

Now, when the script is executed, the amount of time it takes to complete the aggregation is proportional to the number of threads. i.e. the latency linearly increases with number of queries concurrently executed.
Here's the result of script (7 threads executing aggregate queries on different collections):

```
C:\Users\AJINKYA\itanta\live_data>python perf_test3.py Archive-LiveDataLog5 tag1 1
{'_id': '', 'result': 50.054371460796965}
thread 3 completion time:  140.73034977912903
{'_id': '', 'result': 50.20921849745933}
thread 5 completion time:  146.46782159805298
{'_id': '', 'result': 50.064871338705366}
thread 4 completion time:  147.66157269477844
{'_id': '', 'result': 50.17267241078592}
thread 1 completion time:  151.08023619651794
{'_id': '', 'result': 49.85328077580493}
thread 2 completion time:  151.3344430923462
{'_id': '', 'result': 49.993023336937945}
thread 0 completion time:  151.4148395061493
{'_id': '', 'result': 49.89189660585342}
thread 6 completion time:  151.54917550086975
151.57819509506226
```

So it took 151 seconds for 7 threads to finish aggregations.
On the other hand, if there is only single thread executing aggregation on a single collection, it takes much less time. Here's the result if `start_times` in above script has only one element:

```
C:\Users\AJINKYA\itanta\live_data>python perf_test3.py Archive-LiveDataLog5 tag1 1
{'_id': '', 'result': 49.993023336937945}
thread 0 completion time:  43.36866021156311
43.37059950828552
```

It took just 43 seconds if there is only one aggregate query.
My expectation was that the multi-threaded queries would take roughly the same amount of time as the single-threaded one.
Now it's apparent that multiple queries are not executed concurrently in mongodb.
Is this the known limitation of mongodb?
Is there any configuration parameter in mongodb to control concurrency?

Comment: This might be resource starvation on the server.  What do disk utilization and swap usage look like while multiple aggregations are running?  Any operation that takes longer than 100ms should be logged, can we see the log entries for a couple of the slow ones?

Comment: @Joe The disk utilization goes up to 65% when concurrent aggregations are being run. Whereas it's around 30% when only single aggregation is running.
By log entries, do you mean mongod process logs?

Comment: Yes, the mongod should log any operation that takes longer than 100ms to run.

Comment: @Joe There is nothing in the mongo demon logs which is relevant to the aggregation queries being executed concurrently. It gives no clue about the disk latency and aggregation execution. Is there anything else I can look to debug this issue?

Comment: you can lower [slowms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/index.html#specify-the-threshold-for-slow-operations) to 0, then every query will be logged.  If it still doesn't show up then, it's not being processed by that node.

Comment: It turns out that disk latency was the issue. I've checked it by executing separate C programs concurrently which read different files with read() system call. The disk i/o latency increases with each i/o parallel request. It's performance is no different that sequential i/o.